# SIP client in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, voip, sip, asterisk

Newb here.  I am interested in using Ubuntu Phone as a SIP client.

I would really like to hookup with whoever is doing the dialer (or phone app or whatever it is called) in Ubuntu Phone so that VOIP is a built in capability. Android does this but not very well and it's a shame that 3rd party app's are required.  I guess this is why I'm not interested Empathy.

I don't think I am capable of developing this but I want to get involved with a project if I can.

Can someone please direct me on this?  I've been searching around and I don't know where to go.

Comment: See the Wiki page here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch

Comment: That's the page that got me here to askubuntu.com.  Lots of general info but I get lost trying to drill down to the dialer app in particular.

Answer (score 1):

The package source for Ubuntu Touch's system apps can be found here:

[Touch/CoreApps - Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/CoreApps)

This includes the default app, Dialer. As it stands, however, VoIP and SIP don't appear to be integrated with the Ubuntu Touch OS. As such, you would need external APIs to do the Dialer integration you mentioned.

There are two other pages that support this assertion:

[Google Drive - Sources](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1z5BQg-UVKoOXEOe4nuaygvtOrv5irlLR6jARrmxP0I4/edit?usp=sharing)

It's really quite unfortunate, seeing that this would have given Ubuntu Touch a more competitive edge in the mobile market :(

Answer (score 0):

The components of Ubuntu Touch can be found in the Ubuntu Wiki at [wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Components](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Components).

The dialer is called "Phone App" in the list there. It links to the [dialer-app](https://launchpad.net/dialer-app) on Launchpad. This page has all the information about the app, including source code, but it has no associated mailing list.

You could [report a feature request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dialer-app), but I think the best place to ask first is the [ubuntu-phone mailing list](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-phone) (as a Launchpad user you can subscribe from the bottom of that page).

Comment: FYI, I've submitted a [related question](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg16377.html) on the ubuntu-phone mailing list today.

Comment: FYI, this is a related [feature request on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dialer-app/+bug/1533104) (bug #1533104, VOIP).