# Is there a google voice or other VoIP app for Ubuntu phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, voip

I don't see a google voice app available for Ubuntu phone, are there any known plans for this?

Are there any other known VoIP apps available for Ubuntu Phone or any plans for one?

I came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266443/voip-on-ubuntu-for-phones) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262802/sip-client-in-ubuntu-touch), and while they deal with VoIP and Ubuntu Phone, they are unrelated to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the Yate VOIP Client.
Works very well also with multiple SIP accounts.

Tried a few others but working now with Yate for more than 6 months without big problems.